# Django: different behaviour in CreateView and UpdateView with unique constraint

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

```
class Badge(Model):
    # ....

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('identifier', 'restaurant')
```

- Using a `CreateView`, when creating a `Badge` object whose identifier already exists, I actually get a form error, which is the expected behaviour.
- But, using an `UpdateView`, when editing a `Badge` object whose identifier already exists, I don't get any form error, but a 500 error with `duplicate key value violates unique constraint`.

I can't understand why the behaviour differs. I'd like the form error to be shown in both cases.

Comment: Can you share the implementations of your `CreateView` and `UpdateView`?

Comment: I just found my mistake, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I just realised for validation to work, that all fields need to be specified in the class based view, even if these fields should not be filled by the User.

```
class BadgesUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Badge
    # restaurant field must be included for validation even if the user does NOT fill it.
    fields = ('identifier', 'is_active', 'owner', 'restaurant')

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['restaurant'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        return form
```