# Creating modelform to exclude a field loses "nice" handling of unique contraint

Tags: django, django-forms, django-generic-views

I have a model which includes a 'customer' (fk to User), that I have excluded from a custom form (because the logged in user is already known).

The issue I'm having is that I lose the 'nice' form handling for unique constraints once I override the form_valid method to accomodate the excluded field.

models.py:

```
class RequestedData(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    station = models.ForeignKey(Station, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name = 'Measurement Station')
    measurement = models.ForeignKey(Measurement, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Requested Data"
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["customer", "station", "measurement"],
                name="station-measurement-unique",)]
```

The class view is:

```
class RequestedDataCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = RequestedData
    # use overriden form to remove customer from selection
    form_class = RequestedDataForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("requesteddata_list")

    # overwrite form_valid function to add back in user.
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.customer = Customer.objects.get(user__username=self.request.user)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

where you can see I've created a RequestedDataForm to exclude the customer from the form.

```
class RequestedDataForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RequestedData
        exclude = ("customer",)
```

All works well, except when the user enters data in the form that violates the unique constraint.

Before I created the custom form to exclude user (i.e. just using the CreateView form), upon violation of the unique constraint a message would appear as shown below, namely, a very neat label in the html that pops up a message.
[image]

After creating my own form, what now happens is the user gets taken to an ugly error.
[image]

So ultimately, I would like to bring through the same default handling of constraints into my form, but just want to exclude the customer field from the form, given they're logged in so they basically can only select themselves!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56210939/django-different-behaviour-in-createview-and-updateview-with-unique-constraint

Comment: That didn't work quite as expected. It does hide the field on load (get_form), but if there's an error, it refreshes the form to include it...

Answer (score 0):

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
    form.instance.customer = customer
    rendered = render_to_string('render.html')
    response = HttpResponse(rendered)
    try:
        valid_data = super(RequestedDataCreate, self).form_valid(form)
    except IntegrityError as e:
        return response
    return valid_data
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Filter returns a queryset, not an instance; that's why I used the Get method instead.

Comment: I have updated the answer, instead of user.username use user and also you can create a render.html with a nice looking error message to user in case of errors

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `form.instance.customer` after form has been validated and marked as valid - hence you don't get nice errors about unique failing. You should set `customer` in your form before validation.

```py
class RequestedDataCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = RequestedData
    # use overriden form to remove customer from selection
    form_class = RequestedDataForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("requesteddata_list")

    def get_initial(self):
        initials = super().get_initial()
        initials['customer'] = Customer.objects.get(user__username=self.request.user)
        return initials
```

This will set initial customer as the one you want and provide it to form as part of it's kwargs, on form initialization.